# Responsive design behaviour

Tags: css, responsive-design

This is my first responsive site.  I am happy with it however there is one very annoying aspect that has completely stumped me.  The original site is www.elitemarquees.com.au I have changed the home page to:

http://elitemarquees.com.au/test/index.html

The issue is; when I make the browser smaller everything moves and behaves as I intended it except for the menu (#headNav) at one point.  It jumps down into the main content (#content) and sits below the second line of body text.  Then when you go smaller it rectifies its self and jumps back in between the logo (#headLogo) and the main body text.  Here is how I have initially set up the div sections:

```
//this section contains two divs headLogo and headNav
#header {
height: 180px;
}
#headLogo {
width: 250px;
float: left;
}
#headNav {
width: 600px;
float: right;
margin-top: 70px;
padding-right: 40px
}
#content {
width: 500px;
float: right;
padding-right: 140px
}
```

The I do this which is where I believe the bad behaviour occurs:

```
/* for 700px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

#headNav {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
}
#headLogo {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
}
#content {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
}
#sidebar {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
}

}
```

It rectifies its self when this is fired:

```
/* for 480px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

#header {
    height: auto;
}
#headNav {
padding-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
#content {
    padding-right: 10px
}
}
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
/* for 700px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

#headNav {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
}
#headLogo {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
}
#content {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
}
#sidebar {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
}

}
```

You should add this :

```
#header{
        height: auto;
    }
```

Comment: HI @Olivier Thank you for your time.  This didn't chnage the behavior.  I have assumed your solution asked me to set #header width to auto inside the max-width: 700px media query.  Any other ideas

Comment: Excellent that did it.....Can I ask one off-topic question.  Is there an update IE 8 and 9 needs to make the menu responsive that you know about.  Every other browser seems to work well except this one...

Comment: You can use responsive.js : [website](http://responsejs.com/) and  [tutorial](http://nextflow.in.th/en/keep-your-responsive-web-design-against-the-legendary-internet-explorer-ie6ie7ie8/using-response-js-to-make-ie6ie7ie8-understand-your-responsive-design/)